# Setting subitem sorting value on Template?

Tags: templates

Using Sitecore 9.1.1 SXA 1.8.1.

I have a page type where I want its children to always be sorted in reverse.

I know that I can select the page and apply the sorting that way:

[image]

I was hoping I could set it on the template standard values but it's not having an effect (so if it is possible then I'm doing it wrong!)

I do notice jumping back into this dialogue on the standard values seems to have no selection (maybe because it has no children??)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the `Subitems sorting` field on the standard value of the item. Go to the standard value and in the `Appearance` section of the standard fields select the `Subitems sorting` field, update the field and see the changes -

[image]

Comment: Oh that's where it was hiding - thanks :)